# How can I include the derivative of a function as an input to a function handle?

Tags: matlab

Consider the following code snippet corresponding to the solution to the system of ordinary differential equations

da/dt = t*a/(a^2+b^2 + 1)

db/dt = (b-a)^2/(b^2+c^2+1)

dc/dt = t^2*c^2/(a^2+c^2+1)

```
clear;clc;
initial_conditions = [1 0 -1]; 

F=@(t,y) [t.*y(1)./(y(1).^2+y(2).^2+1);
(y(2)-y(1)).^2./(y(2).^2+y(3).^2+1);
t.^2.*y(3).^2./(y(1).^2+y(3).^2+1)];

[t y]=ode23tb(F,[0 2], initial_conditions);

plot(t, y(:,1), 'r', t, y(:,2), 'g', t, y(:,3), 'b')
```

where y(1) corresponds to a, y(2) corresponds with b, and y(3) corresponds with c. How can I include the additional differential equation, 
dz/dt = 5*da/dt, with z(0) = 2 ? I am not sure how to include this in the function handle since It's the derivative of one of the state variables on the right hand-side, and not one of the state variables itself - as the other equations are.

Thanks.

Comment: But `dz/dt` is just a scaled version of `da/dt`, so couldn't you just write it as `dz/dt = 5.*t.*y(1)./(y(1).^2+y(2).^2+1)`?

Comment: yes, this is true. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since `a(t)`, `b(t)` and `c(t)` and their derivatives don't depends on `z(t)` or `dz/dt`, the nature of the problem is still only a 3-unknowns ODE.

So while you can code it as a 4-unknowns ODE and let `ode23()` solves the whole set, it's inefficient.  Just solve `a`, `b`, `c` as your code already does and integrate `z(t)` from `da/dt` that you get out of `ode23()`.